# Tag merge: onboarding and new-hires

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

**Proposal: merge [onboarding](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onboarding) with [new-hires](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-hires)**

- [new-hires](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-hires)

  - Questions: 114
  - Description: (emphasis added)

    > Questions around people that were recently hired, **on boarding practices**, orientations and so forth
- [onboarding](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onboarding)

  - Questions: 3
  - Description: *none*

Comment: I agree, the onboarding tag was just created this year.

Comment: Note: we have [tag:new-hires] (from the company's perspective) and [tag:new-job] (from the employee's perspective). Both can have onboarding questions.

Comment: "Merge" is a bit vague - it can refer to either synonymisation or burnination with retagging.

Comment: @Dukeling You're right. I would vote for _synonymisation_ because `onboarding` is very specific and comes more natural for people, but I'm happy either way

Comment: So... judging by the, currently, +6/-0 I'd say that the burnination with retagging should be carried on (only 3 questions with onboarding). If you may, I can carry out the process. Will wait some time in case someone protests and will then proceed with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just proceeded to do the burnination with retagging. Now [onboarding](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onboarding) has 0 questions.

[image]